# Given a .NET method how can we know what methods, types, etc... does this method make use of?

Tags: .net

Given:

1. A .NET assembly
2. A method belonging to a type inside the assembly (1)

How do I find which .NET types/methods the method (2) references?

I realize reflection does not help here. But what does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to use [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/). You can do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Mono.Cecil;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var a = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
            var m = a.MainModule.Types.Single(c => c.Name == "Program").Methods.Single(c => c.Name == "Main");
            foreach(var inst in m.Body.Instructions)
            {
                switch(inst.Operand)
                {
                    case TypeReference tr:
                        System.Console.WriteLine(tr.FullName);
                        break;

                    case MethodReference mr:
                        System.Console.WriteLine(mr.ReturnType.FullName);
                        System.Console.WriteLine(mr.DeclaringType.FullName);
                        // ....
                        break;

                    // other member types...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, you can also use [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.metadata?view=net-5.0) but, IMO, the latter is much more complex.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with `System.Reflection.Metadata`? I know we can get IL byte stream representing the method body using regular `System.Reflection` library, but that is not really useful to me. The reason why I want to consider another alternative is that I have troubles matching symbol names originating in Mono.Cecil with those from Roslyn static code analysis. I have a relevant question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66499029/how-to-match-type-symbol-names-as-returned-by-roslyn-semantic-model-to-those-ret