# How to match type symbol names as returned by Roslyn semantic model to those returned by Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis, mono.cecil

I have the following piece of code:

```cs
var paramDeclType = m_semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(paramDecl.Type).Type;
```

Where `paramDeclType.ToString()` returns

```cs
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>
```

I also have the same information from Mono.Cecil - `paramDef.ParameterType.FullName` returns

```cs
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Int32>>
```

I would like to compare the type names coming from these two different sources.

I would like to avoid elaborate regex parsing, if possible.

Ideas are welcome.

P.S.

In the meantime, I am going to look for `Mono.Cecil` replacement from Microsoft - System.Reflection.Metadata. Maybe two libraries from Microsoft would be able to produce compatible type names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share the function I currently use:

```
private const string GENERIC_ARG_COUNT_PATTERN = @"`\d+";
private static readonly Regex s_genericArgCountRegex = new Regex(GENERIC_ARG_COUNT_PATTERN);


public static bool IsSameType(this TypeReference typeRef, ITypeSymbol typeSymbol, bool isByRef)
{
    if (isByRef || typeRef.IsByReference)
    {
        return isByRef && typeRef.IsByReference && DoIsSameType(((ByReferenceType)typeRef).ElementType, typeSymbol);
    }

    return DoIsSameType(typeRef, typeSymbol);

    static bool DoIsSameType(TypeReference typeRef, ITypeSymbol typeSymbol)
    {
        var arrayTypeSymbol = typeSymbol as IArrayTypeSymbol;
        var arrayTypeRef = typeRef as ArrayType;
        if (arrayTypeSymbol != null || arrayTypeRef != null)
        {
            return arrayTypeSymbol != null
                && arrayTypeRef != null
                && arrayTypeSymbol.Rank == arrayTypeRef.Rank
                && DoIsSameType(arrayTypeRef.ElementType, arrayTypeSymbol.ElementType);
        }

        // Optimistic approach
        var declFullName = typeSymbol.ToString();
        var typeRefFullName = typeRef.FullName;
        if (typeRefFullName.Contains('`'))
        {
            typeRefFullName = s_genericArgCountRegex.Replace(typeRef.FullName, "");
        }
        if (declFullName == typeRefFullName)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Built-in types - either top level or as generic arguments.
        if (typeRef is GenericInstanceType genTypeRef)
        {
            if (!(typeSymbol is INamedTypeSymbol namedTypeSymbol) ||
                !namedTypeSymbol.IsGenericType ||
                genTypeRef.ElementType.Name != namedTypeSymbol.ConstructedFrom.MetadataName ||
                genTypeRef.GenericArguments.Count != namedTypeSymbol.TypeArguments.Length ||
                genTypeRef.ElementType.Namespace != namedTypeSymbol.ConstructedFrom.ContainingNamespace.ToString())
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < genTypeRef.GenericArguments.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (!DoIsSameType(genTypeRef.GenericArguments[i], namedTypeSymbol.TypeArguments[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        return
            typeRef.Name == typeSymbol.Name &&
            typeRef.IsBuiltInType() &&
            typeSymbol.ContainingNamespace.Name == "System";
    }
}

public static bool IsBuiltInType(this TypeReference t)
{
    return t.Scope.Name == "mscorlib" && DoIsBuiltInType(t);

    static bool DoIsBuiltInType(TypeReference t) => t switch
    {
        ArrayType arrayType => DoIsBuiltInType(arrayType.ElementType),
        ByReferenceType byReferenceType => DoIsBuiltInType(byReferenceType.ElementType),
        _ => t.IsPrimitive || t.Name == "Object" || t.Name == "Decimal" || t.Name == "String",
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, SRM is way more low-level than Mono.Cecil. I've not used it enough to be 100% sure, but AFICS, in SRM you need to provide your own *type system*, meaning, you'll get *type tokens*, *method tokens*, etc, and how you represent that in your program is up to you (this looks way more complex than using Cecil). (You can take a look in ILSpy code https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/tree/master/ICSharpCode.Decompiler to get an idea)

I don't think that converting from Roslyn names -> Cecil names is that hard (of course, depending on your needs). You could try:

1. see if it is possible to ask Roslyn to always use the BLC type names (instead of the C# primitive type names)
2. Remove the ranking information (`1,` 2, etc) and maybe add <> if necessary
3. Replace the nested type separator used by Cecil (/) with a dot (.)
4. Maybe some other cases... :)

That being said, another alternative is to try to map the names to its System.Type equivalent; once you have a System.Type you can call *Module.Import()* in Cecil and get a TypeRefernce back and compare its full name (unfortunately cannot compare two TypeReferences by equality).

Obs: tried to add this as a comment, but it is too long :)

You can use something similar to the code below to figure out the fully qualified type name:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var st = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("class Foo { int i; }");
            var v = st.GetRoot().DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>().Single().Type;
            var pts = (PredefinedTypeSyntax) v;

            var Mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation", syntaxTrees: new[] { st }, references: new[] { Mscorlib });
            var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(st);

            var symbol = model.GetTypeInfo(pts);

            System.Console.WriteLine(symbol.Type.ContainingNamespace.Name + "." + symbol.Type.Name);
            
            // or even something like...
            var intType = model.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeof(int).FullName);
            Console.WriteLine(v.ToString() + "  " + v.GetType().FullName + " " + (symbol.Type.SpecialType == intType.SpecialType));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I resorted to using regex. It is indeed not complicated, though I hoped to avoid it. SRM does look hard. As for your recommendations - I did not find how to make Roslyn use BLC type names.